# Can anyone suggest me how i can write the path to store the output file in which my stored procedure outputs in my oracle DB?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, path, fopen

suppose the IP address of my FTP server is `xx.xxx.xx.xx` and i need the output file to be stored in D:/example. I need to esnure that the path i give is in my FTP server. How can i include that in my fopen function, like a path which points to the example in my FTP server.

Comment: Huh?  are you talking about UTL_FILE.FOPEN?

Comment: Yes, i was referring to the UTL_FILE.FOPEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is how it goes:

- there's a database server
- there is a directory on one of its disks
- that directory will be used in `create directory` command which creates a *directory*, Oracle object
- it will be used as a target for your file-related operations. For example:

  - it'll contain CSV files which are source of external tables
  - .dmp files, result of data pump export, will be stored there (the same goes for import)
  - `UTL_FILE` will create files in that directory

All that means that your idea of creating a file on a FTP server might not work just as easy.

However, there's a way : if you create directory (Oracle object) using UNC (Universal Naming Convention) which points to a directory on the FTP server, the file might be created there. Do some research about it; I know I once did that (put files onto an application server), but that was long time ago and I don't remember everything I did.

Another option you might consider is `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package. Suppose you create a file on the database server (which is the simplest option; if you do it right, it is more or less trivial). Once the procedure (which creates the file) is done, call `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB` using the `executable` job type and call an operating system batch file that will copy the file from the database server to the FTP server.

That's all I can say about it; at least, you have something to research & think about.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.